# Aligning li bullets to the text?

Tags: css

I am using a custom font for the list bullets and normal font for the list content, but since the bullet has a larger font, they items do not align horizontally. I would love any suggestions.

```
@font-face {font-family: altus_extras; src: url('http://localhost:8888/azaleamountain.org/wp-content/fonts/altus_extras.otf');}

.altus li::before { font-family: altus_extras !important; font-size: 6em; content: "/"; }

ul li {list-style-type: none !important;}
```

[image]

```
<ul class="altus">
<li> Is this a nice bullet?</li>
<li> Is this another nice bullet?</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try setting padding of the text to 0, also try using px rather than em for size.

Comment: reducing the font size would be the perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Using line-height that equals the the font-size or the height of the parent element and also vertical-align: middle, will help center the asterisk vertically.

```css
li { 
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;/* space enough to accommodate asterisk size */
  font-weight: 24px;
  
  }


li:after {
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: altus_extras; /* Your custom font */
  font-size: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="altus">
<li> Is this a nice bullet?</li>
<li> Is this another nice bullet?</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3-4 ways of achieving the task:

1. Put position:absolute and then adjust top,left positions for it and put padding-left on li to put space for bullet and position:relative on li to align ::before with it.
2. Put only position:relative on ::before and then put top:5px or 7px as required.
3. Put transform: translate(0px, 7px) on ::before
4. Play with line-height and font size